# Draw Bezier Curve with relative path in SVG

Tags: svg, bezier

I got a very strange question when drawing Bezier Curve in SVG using relative path. At first, I wrote a path with absolute path like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="190px" height="160px" version="1.1"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M110 110 C 120 120, 140 120, 150 110" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>`

And I got a curve like this:
[bezier curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q45FM.png)

But when I used relative path by c, like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="190px" height="160px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M110 110 c 10 10, 20 0, 10 -10" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>`

I got another [bezier curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tShGx.png)

It was totally different. But I think they are actually the same path. What's wrong with me?

Comment: The bezier curve were all shown in Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually say, but I assume you want to know why the paths are different(?)

The reason is because your assumption about how relative coords work is wrong.  All the coords in a relative bezier segment are expressed relative to the last point in the last segment (ie. 110,110). **Not** the last point in the bezier.

```html
<svg width="190px" height="160px">

  <path d="M110 110 C 120 120, 140 120, 150 110" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="10"/>

  <path d="M110 110 c 10 10, 30 10, 40 0" stroke="green" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  If there are multiple triples in a `c`/`C`, for example, the relative coordinates in each triple are actually relative to /the previous triple/, not the last point in the previous segment.    I took this advice and got some /very/ weirdly shaped chess pieces, until I changed it.  =)   See the spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-SVG/

Comment: @BadZen The last triple ***is*** the last segment.  A multi-coords-set path command sequence doesn't count as a single path segment.